# Deleting two characters from printf?

Tags: bash, replace, find, printf

Using GNU find 4.4.2; I am confused at how to backspace the `.\` from the filename:

```
find -name '*' -fprintf foobar "\b\b%h%f\n"
```

How am I meant to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backspacing is purely a cosmetic issue in your terminal and does not delete characters from the data.

`find` prints the `./` because you implicitly ask it to search from `.` (by not providing a path).

You can use `find -printf '%P\n'` to print the path without this search path.

You can also use `find *`, since this makes it search from each (non-hidden) file in the directory instead of the directory itself.

---

As a funny aside, here's how you'd do what you literally asked for:

```
-printf '%H/\b\b%P\n' # Do not use! Read context!
```

This translates to "print search path (`.`) and slash. Print two backspaces to make a terminal hide them, and make all programs consuming the output choke. Then print the path you want."

Obviously this is better simplified to "print the path you want", i.e. `-printf '%P\n'`

Comment: Thanks, that works. I will accept this as answer when SO lets me :)